# Quarkus multimodule build failures after upgrading to 2.0.1.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I followed [this](https://javalibs.com/archetype/net.kemitix/quarkus-multi-module-archetype) (unofficial) archetype to solve errors stating

```
Quarkus code generation phase has failed: Failed to locate <group.id>:<artifact.id> among the project dependencies
```

But further down the line I now face the following error when trying to `mvn install` my project:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for root 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] root ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.373 s]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.767 s]
[INFO] q-entities ......................................... SUCCESS [  2.721 s]
[INFO] submodule-1 ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.222 s]
[INFO] q-app .............................................. FAILURE [  9.532 s]
[INFO] q-tests ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:build (default) on project release-raccoon-app: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.rest.data.panache.deployment.HibernateOrmPanacheRestProcessor#findEntityResources threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find id field of null
```

This happens when the quarkus submodule is being built.

I had a look at the migration guide to 2.0.0 but couldn't find something relevant to my setup.
The error message is a bit cryptic as well and couldn't find where to look for it in the quarkus codebase. Did something change within the new version that needs attention?

Comment: Is this still happening with Quarkus `2.0.2.Final`?

Comment: Woah that's a boatload of bugfixes that was quick :) Unfortunately yes I still get the same error

Comment: What do the generated Panache classes look like?

Comment: `generated-sources` contains an empty `annotations` dir. But that is also the case with the older quarkus version (1.10.5.Final). Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: I mean what does the archetype generate

Comment: That archetype doesn't include an entities module but I have added mine. It can be found here https://github.com/jaivalis/release-raccoon/tree/jdevelop/raccoon-entities
Is there something I should avoid when depending on a separate entities module to the quarkus module?

Comment: It should be working. What you are reporting sounds like a bug, so I would propose you open an issue

Comment: Thanks for your support @geoand! Discussion moved to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18734, please let me know if I'm missing any useful info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be due to the Maven scope of the sub-project being set to `provided`